# Debian can't update after i installed php 8.0

Tags: php, debian

```
Err:1 https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 104.21.18.148 443]
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/bullseye/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 104.21.18.148 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to install  PHP 8.0 on Debian server and this error appeared while updating
how can I remove this.

Comment: or Unix and Linux stack exchange (links to all our sister site in top right icons). You installed an external package, so it is not a problem of Debian. Ask to people responsible to the other repository on how to fix. Probably you need to change address (and distribution name)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68787732/debian-11-update-broke-samueldebruyn-debian-git?noredirect=1#comment121697104_68787732

Comment: I am not willing to continue the installation i just want to remove it

Comment: It literally says `Try installing ca-certificates.` Have you done that? What changed afterwards?